# How to match postal codes to cities name in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have a dataset1 with one variable "postcode" which contains several postal codes. The order of these postal codes is important and could not be changed.

In my second dataset I have 2 variables: "postcode" which contains all postal codes of the country and "city" which contains names of the city that have these postal codes.

My goal: I need to match postal codes from dataset1 with names of the cities from dataset2.

dataset1:

```
postcode
5226
3071
1821
```

dataset2:

```
postcode     city
5226         Leiden
3930         Amsterdam
1821         Almere
1921         Echt
3071         Den Bosch
```

This is the result that I want:

```
city
Leiden
Den Bosch
Almere
```

Comment: Just answered a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192821/adding-same-data-for-same-value-of-variablei-e-id/65198872#65198872) - if this doesn't answer your question, please edit your post and add more information about your situation so we understand how to help

Comment: Hi! thank you for answering! I have added more information about my current problem. I hope it is now more inderstandable.

Comment: ok, this is the exact same situation as in the link I put here above - take a look. Also you can look up `match files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, merging files is the way to go. Make sure the postal code variable has the same name in both files or data sets. Open the one without the city names. Click on Data>Merge Files>Add Variables, identify the file with the cities included, click Continue, and you should see that it'll merge based on key values, which is what you want.